# Echoing text if user not found in database [PHP]

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'lol', 'api');
$name2 = $session->username;
$nokey = "You don't have an API key."; 

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM apikey WHERE username = '$name2';");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

echo "<p>Your API Key: " . $row['apikey'] . "</p>";
}
?>
```

I an having trouble making it echo $nokey if there username is not in the database. I have tried multiple things but nothing had worked out. Hoping someone here can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether any rows were returned by your query. Something like this should work:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'lol', 'api');
$name2 = $session->username;
$nokey = "You don't have an API key."; 

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM apikey WHERE username = '$name2'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "<p>Your API Key: " . $row['apikey'] . "</p>";
    }
} else {
    // this is the new bit
    echo $nokey;
}
?>
```

Comment: You're right; sorry! Seems strange not to be using PDO.

Comment: Not every user uses PDO. Anyways +1

Comment: Well yes, I realise that. Although here it would certainly help avoid Little Bobby Tables paying a visit with that `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 3):

Run this code right after $query

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
       echo "<p>Your API Key: " . $row['apikey'] . "</p>";
    }
} else {
   echo $nokey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "lol";
    $dbname = "api"; 
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $name2 = $session->username;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM apikey WHERE username = '$name2';";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<p>Your API Key: " . $row['apikey'] . "</p>";
        }
    }
    else{
         echo "You don't have an API key.";
    }

?>
```

Try this.